# What is the correct way to handle someone charging through an unknown invisible enemy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, invisibility, charge

In a recent session, an enemy creature tried to charge at our spellcaster. Unknown to him, our Rogue, who had Invisibility cast on him, was in the way. What is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## RAW

### The Charge is stopped

The rules for charging state:

> You must have a clear path toward the opponent, and nothing can hinder your movement (such as difficult terrain or obstacles). You must move to the closest space from which you can attack the opponent. If this space is occupied or otherwise blocked, you can’t charge. If any line from your starting space to the ending space passes through a square that blocks movement, slows movement, or contains a creature (even an ally), you can’t charge. Helpless creatures don’t stop a charge.

The invisible rogue will prevent the charge due to this rule. The question is what happens *after* the enemy charges into the rogue, and RAW doesn't do a great job of covering this.

This movement would be considered illegal and come under the ending in an illegal space rule.

> **[Accidentally Ending Movement in an Illegal Space](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#special-movement-rules)**: Sometimes a character ends its movement while moving through a space where it’s not allowed to stop. When that happens, put your miniature in the last legal position you occupied, or the closest legal position, if there’s a legal position that’s closer.

Sourced from this question on [walking into an invisible pc](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90266/what-happen-when-an-npc-unknowingly-walks-into-an-invisible-pc). You should read the answer there, they are quite relevant.

### Does the invisibility break?

Only if the rogue takes an attack of opportunity. Which they are entitled to thanks to the creature moving through a square they threaten.

## Potential Rulings

### Attempt an overrun

The creature can attempt to overrun the invisible rogue with an appropriate penalty for being unaware of their presence. This should would probably still stop the charge but that's up to you as the DM.

### Make an acrobatics check

You could allow the rules on using acrobatics to [move through an enemies square](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics/#move-through-threatened-area). This would not provoke an attack of opportunity if successful but stops movement on a fail. I wouldn't allow this due to invisibility but it is an option.

### Let the rogue decide

They are in this position due to clever play, I would employ the *rule of cool* and let the rogue decide how they would like to play it. Let them make a combat check to trip, or an aoo, or choose to avoid the charge and remain invisible.

Comment: *An Aside:* Seriously, has no developer ever put to paper explicit rules for what happens if a dude tries to enter an invisible creature's space? I mean, this game runs off a nearly-2-decades-old engine and *still* has never in any of its iterations officially addressed questions like this? The spell *invisibility* is 2nd-level, for heaven's sakes! People actually *play* at levels it's available! Argh! (Not a slam against this answer, of course, but just my own general frustration.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Agreed. I would have thought it existed in some errata or something but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: It's just so bizarre. [Charging](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58195/8610) *and* [overrunning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58102/8610) are both a mess, and the solution seems to be *Hey, let's make* Pathfinder 2!

Comment: @HeyICanChan To be fair, the rest of Pathfinder is also a mess.

Comment: @MarkWells But it believes deep down in its little heart that it's not, and, as everyone knows, that's all that really matters. `:-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan Any system that hangs around long enough with be exposed as fundamentally flawed in some way or another. That's why house rules exist right?

Answer (score 2):

#### RAW, they either stop or take an acrobatics check to move through an opponent's square, if applicable.

First, the Rogue may choose whether or not to take an Attack of Opportunity, as the creature is attempting to move through a threatened square.

> Threatened Squares
>
> You threaten all squares into which you can make a melee attack, even when it is not your turn. Generally, that means everything in all squares adjacent to your space (including diagonally). An enemy that takes certain actions while in a threatened square provokes an attack of opportunity from you.

[Later under "Moving through a Square"](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/)

> You can’t move through a square occupied by an opponent unless the opponent is helpless. You can move through a square occupied by a helpless opponent without penalty.

[Under Acrobatics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics/)

> Move Through Threatened Squares
>
> In addition, you can move through a threatened square without provoking an attack of opportunity from an enemy by using Acrobatics. When moving in this way, you move at half speed. You can move at full speed by increasing the DC of the check by 10. [...] If you attempt to move through an enemy’s space and fail the check, you lose the move action and provoke an attack of opportunity.

So the opponent (if applicable) can take an acrobatics check at +15 CMD (+5 for the acrobatic's base check to move through their square, +10 additionally for full-speed) to bypass the AoO and move through the rogue's square. NOTE: if he fails this check, he loses the move action and he's done (paused in front of the Rogue and taking an AoO if so desired.)

NOTE: The opponent cannot use the Overrun maneuver, by pure RAW, because Overrun specifies a target (the target of your charge) that you would attempt to use the combat maneuver on.

Comment: How can they "attempt to overrun" a creature they don't know is there?

Comment: Actually, I misread, as overrun requires a target. I will amend that.

Comment: Also, moving through an enemy's space (rather than just through a threatened space) is an additional +5 DC. (I don't see how that's possible at all when they _can't see the guy_, but ignoring that for the moment...)

Comment: @blurry in addition to your DCs being a little off, you are ignoring the creature is unaware of the presence of the Rogue...so, he wouldn't be likely to take any voluntary actions to avoid AoOs (unless incredibly careful or paranoid), and would also be unable to attempt to move through the occupied square. Assuming the creature somehow is attempting to move through an Occupied Square, the DC would be 5 + the Rogue's CMD, potentially plus the full speed movement modifier, depending on how far the creature needed to move to charge.

Comment: @YogoZuno The DC was based on my assumption of them moving full speed (+10), but I did indeed miss the extra +5 in my haste. I've amended that to be more clear.

Comment: @MarkWells I've amended the DCs
I could make it so the answer says they probably stop; or that it's GMs discretion whether they stop or whether they do acrobatics. I think straight RAW they qualify for "move through a threatened square" and then potentially acrobatics; regardless of their knowledge of the situation. Certainly for immersion you may mitigate this; though thus far I'm pointing out the only RAW solution to *not* just stopping.